# Vertical order traversal of a binary tree: when nodes overlap

Tags: c++, tree, queue, binary-tree

I am working on the LeetCode problem [987: Vertical Order Traversal of a Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/vertical-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree, calculate the **vertical order traversal** of the binary tree.
>
> For each node at position `(row, col)`, its left and right children will be at positions `(row + 1, col - 1)` and `(row + 1, col + 1)` respectively. The root of the tree is at `(0, 0)`.
>
> The **vertical order traversal** of a binary tree is a list of top-to-bottom orderings for each column index starting from the leftmost column and ending on the rightmost column. There may be multiple nodes in the same row and same column. In such a case, sort these nodes by their values.
>
> Return *the **vertical order traversal** of the binary tree.*

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> verticalTraversal(TreeNode* root) 
    {
        map<int, map<int, vector<int> > > nodes; // actual mapping
        queue<pair<TreeNode*, pair<int, int> > > q; // for storing in queue along with HD and level no.
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        vector<int> cur_vec;
        
        if(!root){
            return ans;
        }
        
        q.push(make_pair(root, make_pair(0, 0)));
        
        while(!q.empty()){
            pair<TreeNode*, pair<int, int> > temp = q.front(); // for storing the queue.front value in temp
            q.pop();
            TreeNode* frontNode = temp.first;
            int hd = temp.second.first;
            int level = temp.second.second;
            
            nodes[hd][level].push_back(frontNode->val);
            
            if(frontNode->left)
                q.push(make_pair(frontNode->left, make_pair(hd-1, level+1)));
            if(frontNode->right)
                q.push(make_pair(frontNode->right, make_pair(hd+1, level+1)));
        }
        for(auto i: nodes){
            for(auto j: i.second){
                for(auto k: j.second){
                    cur_vec.push_back(k);
                } 
            }             
            ans.push_back(cur_vec);
            cur_vec.resize(0);
        }     
        return ans;          
    }
};
```

I've used a multidimensional map in my answer which maps horizontal distance to levels. It works for several test cases, but it fails to pass the test case when two nodes overlap each other and the smaller one has to come first.

For instance, here the correct output for one vertical line is [1,5,6] but mine is [1,6,5] (the overlapping nodes are 6 and 5):

[image: Output of failed testcase]

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final loop, you can just add a call to `sort` on the inner vector (that corresponds to a certain horizontal distance and certain level). It is in that vector you could get overlapping nodes.

So:

```cpp
        for(auto i: nodes){
            for(auto j: i.second){
                sort(j.second.begin(), j.second.end());  // <-- added
                for(auto k: j.second){
                    cur_vec.push_back(k);
                } 
            }             
            ans.push_back(cur_vec);
            cur_vec.resize(0);
        }
```

Comment: thank you. it worked. was doing it but didn't know where to place that line